# How does the powershell cmd-let 'Invoke-SqlCmd' connect to the SQL server?

Tags: powershell, rest, http, networking, database-connection

I understand the functionality of the cmd-let -- provide a server, database name, user name, password and powershell is using those credentials to create your desired connection. What I don't understand is **how** it is making that connection. To my knowledge, SQL servers don't have built in REST APIs, and even would it be safe to transport those types of credentials over a basic HTTP request? Maybe there is something basic that I am missing here but I don't see anything in the Microsoft docs, and my searches are fruitless at the moment. Any help or direction pointing would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's using classes in the .NET namespace [System.Data.SqlClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0), specifically `SqlCommand`.